# datatables not showing data from json file on localhost

Tags: jquery, json, datatables-1.10

Datatables not getting data from json file , i don't know how to fix ,it showing 404 error , file access error

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#example').dataTable( {

   "ajax": "data.json"

   } );

   } );

 </script>
```

/-----------------------------------------------------------/

```
{
"data": [
   [

  "Tiger Nixon",
  "System Architect",
  "Edinburgh",
  "5421" 
],
[
  "Garrett Winters",
  "Accountant",
  "Tokyo",
  "8422"
],
[
  "Ashton Cox",
  "Junior Technical Author",
  "San Francisco",
  "1562"
   ]
]
}
```

Comment: what is the message in the console?

Comment: http://localhost:56341/wp-admin/user.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @Arun

Comment: Not with css. with datatables??

Comment: only this error in console !

Comment: console showing no error @Arun

Comment: Try wrapping your code inside `jQuery(function($) {  });` instead of document.ready.. Or you might have missed datatable respective JS files.

Comment: i tried that but datatable is showing but no data inside it @Arun

Comment: http://localhost:56341/wp-admin/data.json?_=1431949993409  ,  i tried but now this error arise

Comment: Your json seems not to be valid in jsonlint

Comment: JSON is valid , i checked it @cs04iz1

Comment: GET http://jobify/data.json?_=1432014398558  // thats error i'm getting in console @Arun

Comment: Finally i fixed it by  myself , i'm doing this in wordpress , wordpress doesn't accept .json extension , so i cahnged the file extension to .text and gave it relative path

Comment: Please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted so the question is closed and those having the similar problem would be able to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed it by myself , i'm doing this in wordpress , wordpress doesn't accept .json extension , so i cahnged the file extension to .text and gave it relative path –